# NGINX – Serving multiple SPA’s on a single server

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

We have a development server with lots of single page apps that also handle routing in the frontend.

Normally for a single page app I would assume you need to configure something like:

```
location /some/path {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
}
```

Now on our development server it is quite a lot of work to re-configure nginx for every small test app people put on there.

**I want to:**

- Serve the file if found
- Serve the index.html file if the path is a folder
- If not found, go back one folder and try look for index.html and serve that
- Try previous step until you find an index.html file
- Stop trying when you reach the defined root path e.g. /some/path, if that doesn’t have an index.html, return the folder content

If some sort of while loop is not possible (performance is less critical since it's for development purposes only), I could limit it to up to 6 folders back. That should cover most SPA's.

**Example:**

Let's say I have a single page app on:

```
/some/path/my-app
```

And one goes to:

```
/some/path/my-app/page1/subpage2/id3
```

It should try:

- /some/path/my-app/page1/subpage2/id3 (no match)
- /some/path/my-app/page1/subpage2/id3/index.html (no match)
- /some/path/my-app/page1/subpage2/index.html (no match)
- /some/path/my-app/page1/index.html (no match)
- /some/path/my-app/index.html (MATCH !)

*P.S. I'm mainly a front-end developer, my nginx knowledge is very limited.*

Answer (score 3):

You can use a named location as the last parameter of a `try_files` statement to perform an internal `rewrite` to climb up the directory tree. Nginx will limit this to about 10 iterations before declaring a redirection loop.

For example:

```
root /path/to/root;
index index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.+/)?. /$1 last;
}
```

The `index` and `try_files` directives handle looking for `index.html`, and the `rewrite` statement truncates the URI by removing one or more characters following a `/`.

Comment: the `rewrite` regex should be `^/(.+/)?.+`

Comment: @javen `^/(.+/)?.+` and `^/(.+/)?.` both match the same URLs. Because there is no end of string anchor (`$`), they only match the **beginning** of the URL and don't care how many additional characters follow.